# Anti-Spam filter

Tags: feature-request

There is a guy that does this every few days:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678595/conversion-from-type-dbnull-to-type-string-is-not-valid-asp-netvb-closed

It can be easily blocked if you add an automatic spam detector, and have the moderators or people with 50000 reputation the tools to add spam patterns to that detector list (for example - that dude's site address.)

Just an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [delete] key still works just fine ;-p

The problem with automated filters is that you end up in a war of subtle tweaks, and it isn't hugely beneficial. Those answers take almost no time to deal with manually. Just keep flagging / voting / etc. By now they easily qualify for nuking from orbit, so just add your flag => require moderator attention and quickly vacate the blast area...

Comment: +1 I rue the day I took over maintenance of spam filters...  Good riddance to it, and printers.  I would much rather see another mod or two if the current group is getting overwhelmed than seeing spam filter wars erupt.

Comment: As long as setting the flag will get them deleted before indexed by google - it will do the work.

Answer (score 3):

We *may* implement a blacklist of some kind (this typically means URLs, since they are almost by definition unique) but to date it hasn't really been necessary.

Comment: and then they switch to tinyurl, bit.ly, etc.

Comment: They won't, don't worry. Real spammers want their URLs out there. They call it SEO.

Comment: That was the idea behind this suggestion...

Answer (score 2):

The community **is** the spam filter.

When/if there are six (6) flags on a post, it automatically gets deep-sixed from and by the system.

If it's egregiously persistent then there are other measures such as IP blocking.